# Cannot run Tomcat server on browser?

Tags: osx, webserver, tomcat

I followed the guide in [HERE](http://omnis-MacBook-Air:bin%20omni$%20sudo%20./startup.sh%20Using%20CATALINA_BASE:%20%20%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src%20Using%20CATALINA_HOME:%20%20%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src%20Using%20CATALINA_TMPDIR:%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/temp%20Using%20JRE_HOME:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home%20Using%20CLASSPATH:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar%20touch:%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/logs/catalina.out:%20No%20such%20file%20or%20directory%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/catalina.sh:%20line%20429:%20/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/logs/catalina.out:%20No%20such%20file%20or%20directory) to install Tomcat 8.0.36 (binary version) on my El Capitan by downloading it from its website but it gives me error when I try to start it through terminal.  Please help!

```
omnis-MacBook-Air:bin omni$ sudo ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/catalina.sh: line 429: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
```

---

UPDATE: I created a log folder in tomcat folder and now it says tomcat started but when I run localhost: 8080 it's not working (Site can't be reached)

```
omnis-MacBook-Air:bin omni$ ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:            /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-   src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Here's Catalina.out

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap   
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

Comment: I'm guessing that log directory doesn't exist. Maybe create it??

Comment: @JeffSchaller UPDATE: i created a log folder in tomcat folder and now it says tomcat started but when i run localhost: 8080 it's not working

Comment: You'll have to give us more to work with than that. What's the error or output , and what's in the Catalina.out file? Edit it into the Q.

Comment: it says This site can’t be reached
in browser

Comment: @JeffSchaller I uploaded errors

Comment: Are you sure that you downloaded the binaries? The directory is of the source distribution and that is a common error when the binaries are not present.

Comment: Yes under binary distribution tar.gz how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem today and found a way to fix it without having to download the binary distribution.

Assuming you followed the instructions in BUILDING.txt successfully, you only need to change the CATALINA_HOME to ${tomcat.source}/output/build and everything should work just fine.

In fact, there's a file called RUNNING.txt which specifically notes:

> As an alternative to downloading a binary distribution, you can
>   create your own from the Tomcat source code, as described in
>   "BUILDING.txt".  You can either
>
> a)  Do the full "release" build and find the created distribution in the
>         "output/release" directory and then proceed with unpacking as above, or
>
> b)  **Do a simple build and use the "output/build" directory as
>         "CATALINA_HOME"**. Be warned that there are some differences between the
>         contents of the "output/build" directory and a full "release"
>         distribution.

The error "Could not find or load main class..." happens when CATALINA_HOME is set to ${tomcat.source} where there is no necessary generated classes. Those are stored under output/classes after building.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally downloaded source distribution according to your CATALINA_BASE variable (notice -src at the end of the path):

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src

You should download the binary distribution.